# Laravel eloquent search

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

I am currently using this package for search https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence it works well but having problem with my database column that contains data with a format like this "yellow,green,blue,black" which is not searchable as a key, any idea how to make my color as one of the search key?

here is what i currently have inside my controller

```
User::search($request->input('search-key'),
        $fulltext = false)->get();
```

and this is what i have inside model

```
protected $searchableColumns = [
    'age' => 20,
    'colors' => 10,
    'section' => 2,
    'name' => 1
];
```

Comment: example data from db
name: john doe
age: 7
section: c1
colors: pink,white,red,violet